# Error CRUD code generation using Gii

Tags: php, yii2

I am new to Yii2.
I am not able to generate CRUD code in Gii.
Constantly getting error.

```
 PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
mkdir(): File exists
1. in /var/www/html/yii/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-gii/Generator.php at line 226
   public function saveStickyAttributes()
    {
        $stickyAttributes = $this->stickyAttributes();
        $stickyAttributes[] = 'template';
        $values = [];
        foreach ($stickyAttributes as $name) {
            $values[$name] = $this->$name;
        }
        $path = $this->getStickyDataFile();
        @mkdir(dirname($path), 0755, true);  <------- 226 
        file_put_contents($path, json_encode($values));
    }
```

With what it can be connected? the right to a folder placed correctly.

Environment:

- Vagrant
- precise64
- PHP 5.5.26
- Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)

Comment: You have to delete existing file where it's located and try again or you have to change file name.

Comment: deleted files models and  views  -  It d`t help ((

Comment: try deleting directory and recreate it.

Comment: I follow the guide  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html , I do not understand how there folder can be deleted, possibly an error in the rights to the folder?

Comment: may be you are right. Check for permission on your project directory.

Comment: no rights to folders all okay  (

Comment: can you show image of GII where you get error.

Comment: yes, https://hsto.org/files/b25/bc9/00d/b25bc900dd6a4538b4e7b954eff08d7c.png

Comment: you must delete directory where you were creating file. Delete all controller, model and view files.

Comment: you are creating `model` or `view`?

Comment: I deleted a folder the error persists ((

Comment: ok then try: `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/ProjectDirectory`

Comment: No, it did not help ((( Here is the complete error page https://www.dropbox.com/s/6x723z5cb21b3vc/yii_base_ErrorException.html?dl=0

Comment: Can you post the view path you put in gii?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable Xdebug in php.ini